# C# for Windows Phone 7, why this language

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to find a concrete arguments, why C# was chosen for Windows Phone platform?

Comment: Thats a good question, i was just wondering the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO. C# is the most popular language in the .NET world. As soon as Windows Phone platform - Silverlight, C# was chosen.

Comment: so am i to understand that i can`t use VB.NET to wite code for WP?

Comment: @Freeman I'm aware that there was a VB.NET CTP for Windows Phone, but I'm still not sure was it ever released. So I guess you better should use C#. Good news that in Windows Phone 8 development you will be able to use VB.NET when SDK and tools will be released.

Comment: In my opinion the answer is that c# was not chosen as the favourite language intenationaly (i have friends that made WP apps in F# also, though not sure how) and yes it can also be done in VB.NET and Python.NET, but it is very widely used because of the resemblence to c-like programming languages .